# How to use label on tab bar controller?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to get label or button on tab bar controller, but the area seems to be disabled. Can anyone help, Thaanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for reference purpose.

```
extension UITabBarController {
   func addLabelAtTabBarItemIndex(tabIndex: Int, value: Int) {
        let tabBarItemCount = CGFloat(self.tabBar.items!.count)
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)))
        label.text = "\(value)"
        self.tabBar.addSubview(label)
   }
}
```

Here keep in mind that your origin of label is the very important. That's why is had created one variable "tabBarItemCount" which could give counts of your tab bars and as per tabIndex parameter you can apply it on respective tab bar.
Just apply this as per your tab index.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I tried your code and it works perfectly. Thanks